# How do I use Prolog to solve Transportation Problem?

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming

I am working on a Prolog assignment in class, and I don't know exactly how to get it to work. The problem is:

- Given an initial solution and specifications for both supply and demand, generate an optimal solution using the stepping stone method

I have already designed a solution in golang and java, but I really have no idea how Prolog works to get this done.

Does anyone have anywhere to start? or at the very least, does anyone know of a good resourse I can use to figure out my problem?

Comment: I'm afraid this is a little too broad for Stack Overflow. If you look through answers we already have for similar problems and take a crack at it, maybe we can help you get over a hump, but "how do I approach this problem" is not concrete enough for us to help you with.

Comment: For Prolog this looks like a problem best modeled in [tag:clpq] or [tag:clpr].